# show that the set of all 2-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

show that the set of all 2-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable

could someone guide me through this problem?

Comment: Isn't it naturally a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: is $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ isn't a subset of $\Bbb N$, but it is countable.  And infinite subsets of countable sets are countable.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Let $\{a,b\}$ be a pair of natural numbers, then $a<b$ or $b<a$. Without loss of generality $a<b$. Then the map $\{a,b\}\mapsto 2^a3^b$ is injective.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the same technique as you did to prove that the set of rationals is countable.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the set of all finite subsets of 
$\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

For any such set,
$K = \{k_i\}_{i=1}^m$
where each $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$,
map $K$ into
$\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{k_i}$
where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime.

By unique factorization, the map is into,
so the set of finite subsets is countable.

Answer (score 0):

The set of subsets $\{a, b\}$ with $a < b$ is countable, and each of them is countable. So what you are looking at is a countable union of countable sets, thus countable.

Comment: It seems like what you argument shows is that $\mathbb{N}$ itself is countable.