# Prove that $ℕ^n$ is countable for every n∈ℕ.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove that $ℕ^n$ is countable for every n∈ℕ**

I'm stuck please help this quesion

Comment: *Inducation*.${}$

Comment: Related: [Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [show that the set of all 2-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386808/show-that-the-set-of-all-2-element-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable)

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and $p_1,\dots,p_n$ be distinct primes. Consider $f:\mathbf{N}^n\to\mathbf{N}$ given by $f(m_1,\dots,m_n)=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_n^{m_n}$. What can you deduce from such a function?

Answer (score 9):

A typical element of the product set is something like (3,58,15), the case $(n=3)$.
Consider base 11 number system where this represents a unique (positive) integer
by treating comma as symbol (digit) for ten:
So the example above represents 
 $$ 5  + ( 1\times 11) + (10\times 11^2)+ (8\times 11^3) + (5\times 11^4)
+(10\times 11^5)  +(3\times11^6)$$
This gives an injective function to positive integers, so the product set is countable.

Comment: Never seen that before! That's pretty clever :)

Comment: @ Stella Biderman. I don't deserve the credit. Not my original. Read it in American Math Monthly (don't know the author) 25 years ago. That proof  was for rational numbers where $1/2$ is read as a base 11 integer treating the slash as digit 10. I reused for this case.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: note that $\mathbb{N}^n =\mathbb{N}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{N}$.  If you've proven that $\mathbb{N}^{n-1}$ is countable, then this must be the same as $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.