# $\Bbb N$x$\Bbb N$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove $\Bbb N$x$\Bbb N$ is countably infinite?
Is the proof in some book about sets?
Somebody help please.

Comment: This has been answered earlier. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714998/prove-that-%e2%84%95n-is-countable-for-every-n%e2%88%88%e2%84%95/715016#715016

Comment: I think the problem it's a little bit different..isn't it?

Comment: It is the SAME.

Comment: ah ok with n=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the proof that the rationals are countably infinite? This is precisely the same idea.

Think if you lay out elements in a grid as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
(1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) & \ldots \\
(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & \ldots \\
(3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now enumerate them on the diagonals:

(1,1)

(2,1), (1,2)

(3,1), (2,2), (1,3)

(4,1), (3,2), (2,3), (1,4)

etc. etc.

Can you see how you'll get every element of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?
If the element $(x,y)$ is such that $x+y = n$, then you'll encounter it on the $(n-1)$st diagonal.

Comment: yes it's clear, and then how I proceed?

Comment: Well then you're essentially done, you've shown that you can enumerate all of the elements of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ in a list.  The first element of the list is $(1,1)$, the second element is $(2,1)$, the third is $(1,2)$, and so on.  In other words you have established a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.  This is the definition of "countably infinite."

Comment: I see, thanks Badam Baplan

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that a countable union of countable sets is countable? If so, you could write

$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$

Where each $E_i = \{i\}\times \mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Also, if you interpreted a ratio $a/b$ as a pair $(a,b)$, there is the following trick: http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/rational-numbers-countable.php  This technique can be found and described many different places by google searching for an enumeration of the rational numbers.